# Simple way to send php post data with no form

Tags: php, post, multipartform-data

I have a file called "receive_data.php" on my server, that receives POST data from excel vba constantly throughout the day. This file inserts data into the database as a log of which tools and reports are being used throughout the day for the business I work for.

I have now created a report that is generated onscreen when php file "show_data.php" is viewed.

When show_data.php is viewed, ideally I would like to 'ping' "receive_data.php" with similar values as below:

```
$_POST['code'] = 1;
$_POST['r_id'] = 24;
```

The company I work for uses very old browsers, therefore using something like AngularJS is not an option as it can be unreliable in anything older than IE9.

I could include "receive_data.php" within the php file, but it's still a case of being able to have the variables sent in as 'post' variables.

I could modify the "receive_data.php" file to accept variables, however...

**Ultimately I do not want to modify "receive_data.php" in any way, if at all possible.**

If this is possible, then great!  If not, then I will have to look at modifying the file, but due to the business intensive needs, editing it is worse for us.

Comment: Google: ajax. You're welcome.

Comment: Note: The reason i do not want to edit the "receive_data.php" file is because it receives 1000's of transactions an hour. It isnt worth the risk of losing usage data for 100's of employees should the script linger or fail during edit/copy/paste etc.

Comment: @Saturnix - AngularJS/AJAX...javascript in general is a no. Mostly disabled on our local intranet. I want to know specifically if there is a way to submit within the PHP code.

Comment: Of course you can use AJAX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '<path_to_your_script>/receive_data.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "code=1&r_id=14");
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
  }
```